# Angular.js: How to access nested object literals

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have the following data structure:

```
{ 
    current: { Number: '8', AnotherNumber: 123 },
}

{ 
    current: { Number: '9', AnotherNumber: 456 },
}
```

I want in angular view to print out in a table:

```
Number  AnotherNumber
8       123
```

I am trying with this, but it is displaying the whole current object

```
  <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in friend">
            {{friend.current}}
        </span>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a single `friend` element in your case is an object `{current:{}}` to iterate through keys and values you should do something like:

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
    <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in friend.current">
        {{key}} {{value}}
    </span>
</li>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/hWKl262YIi0IBhIebJGz?p=preview working plnkr example

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>AnotherNumber</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        <td>{{friend.current.Number}}</td>
        <td>{{friend.current.AnotherNumber}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

Unrelated to the question, but yu can do this for brevity:

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Number</th><th>AnotherNumber</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends" ng-init="c=friend.current">
        <td>{{c.Number}}</td><td>{{c.AnotherNumber}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want, you can iterate "blindly" over the keys, but that will result in the columns being sorted alphabetically (unless you add more code to specify their order explicitely):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="key in firends[0]">{{key}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        <td ng-repeat="(key value) in friends">{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/k63uzfc1/)**.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I don't want to access by name, but iterate "blindly", since I am getting that JSON from a schemaless MongoDB.

Comment: @SirBenBenji: Yeah, you probably should :) Check out my updated answer for the "catch" in iterating over object keys.